# How to pass selected option to another page

Tags: php, html

while I'm working with a Select Tag, nothing is displayed as can not be seen in the second page using $_SESSION variables. Someone helps me: I'm so confused:
My first page:

```
  <?php
    session_start();
    if(isset($_SESSION['a'])){
        echo $_SESSION['a'];
    }
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    </head>

    <body>
    <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="test2.php">
      <label for="df"></label>
      <input type="text" name="df" id="df" />
      <select name="a">
      <option value="12" />12

      <option value="13"/>13

      </select>
      <input type="submit" value="send" />
    </form>
    <?php
    if(isset($_post)){
        if(isset($_POST['a'])){
    $_SESSION['a']= $_POST['a'];
    }
    }
    ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

My second Page:

```
 <?php
    session_start();
    $r12=13;
    if(isset($_SESSION['a'])){
        echo $r12;
    }

    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    </head>

    <body>

    aaa
    <?php

    if(isset($_SESSION['a'])){
        echo $_SESSION['a'];
    }
    ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4559474/html-form-select-submit

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="submit" value="send" name="submit"/>
```

and

```
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `isset($_post)`, this should be `isset($_POST)`

Answer (score 0):

You are posting to `test2.php`, so only `test2.php` will receive the `$_POST`, not the first page!

If you call `var_dump($_POST)` on the *second* page, you should see the variables being sent. But `$_POST` will be empty when the form is displayed on the *first* page (i.e. before the form is submitted).

Answer (score 0):

This will work: Just set the $_POST['a'] as a session and you can use it also at your other page.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        echo $_POST['a'];
        }
    else{
    ?>
<head>
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="form1" method="post" action="index.php">
    <input type="text" name="df" id="df" />
        <select name="a">
            <option value="12" >12</option>
            <option value="13">13</option>
        </select>
    <input type="submit" value="send" name='submit' />
    </form>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It is never necessary to duplicate your option text as the option's `value` attribute.  Just omit that bit of markup bloat.

Answer (score 0):

This is another way and Your first page should be something like this..

```
<?php
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['a'])){
   echo $_SESSION['a'];
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
   <title>Untitled Document</title>
 </head>
 <body>
   <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post">
      <label for="df"></label>
        <input type="text" name="df" id="df" />
      <select name="a">
         <option value="12" />12
         <option value="13"/>13
        </select>
      <input type="submit" value="send" name="submit"/>
   </form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
   if(isset($_POST['a'])){
      $_SESSION['a']= $_POST['a'];
        $url = 'test2.php'; // Define the URL:      
        header("Location: $url");
        exit(); // Quit the script.         
    }
}
?>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
if(isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST)){
 echo 'your selected option : '.$_POST['a'];
}
```