# How to pass values from javascript to PHP and then passing to an oracle database as an integer

Tags: javascript, php, database, oracle

Hi I have a problem passing values from javascript to PHP(in a separate file)

```
function checked(){  
        var length = document.getElementById("Options").length; 
        alert(length); 
        for(var i = 0;  i < length - 1; i++){
            if(document.getElementById(i).checked){
                var selectedId = i; 
                var slecetedValue = document.getElementById(i).value; 
            }
        } 
    }
```

These are the variables calculated in the javascript function. 
But I need to pass them to a seperate php file to send them to an ORACLE database (hopefully as integers). How exactly can I fix this problem?

Also, how exactly can I send a an integer to an oracle database cause oci_by_name normally sends a varchar but I need a Number.

PS. I know there are examples online but I don't really understand could you give me an example ?

Thanks you

Comment: What examples do You not understand?

Comment: I actually just got this code window.location.href = "http://localhost/project/delete.php?selectedId=" + selectedId + "&selectedOption=" + selectedOption; and worked just fine. But I have a problem passing an integer into an ORACLE database instead of a varchar any ideas?

Comment: I think It would be better to delete this question and write new about inserting integer from PHP into Oracle. Or find it.

Answer (score 0):

You would use AJAX. Here is a good starting point with an example of JavaScript sending data to a PHP script running on the server. [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/)

Or you could submit the html form to the server and pass the data to a PHP script as is answered in this stackoverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4559474/html-form-submit-to-php-script)

Comment: I actually found this  window.location.href = "http://localhost/project/delete.php?selectedId=" + selectedId + "&selectedOption=" + selectedOption;

Comment: But do you have any idea how can I pass an integer into an ORACLE DATABASE?

Comment: When the data is passed to the PHP script, you could use the PHP function intval to get the integer that you pass on to the Oracle DB in your query. http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php